# Haskell stack build including makefile

Tags: haskell, cabal, ffi, haskell-stack

I am developing a library that uses some C bindings via `inline-c`. As of now, the build process involves a makefile, as follows, since we first need to produce C stubs from the inline-c macros, compile them into object code and link them dynamically, in this case to GHCi.

```
step1:
    ghc ${SRCDIR}/Internal/InlineC.hs -isrc/

step2:
    cc -c ${SRCDIR}/Internal/InlineC.c -o ${LIBDIR}/InlineC_c.o -I${PETSC_DIR_ARCH}/include -I${PETSC_DIR}/include

step3:
    ghci ${SRCDIR}/Test.hs ${SRCDIR}/Internal/InlineC.hs  ${LIBDIR}/InlineC_c.o  ${LIBDIR}/Internal.o -isrc/ -L${PETSC_DIR_ARCH}/lib -lpetsc -lmpich
```

### Question

Is there a way to package up the above build sequence in a `stack build` recipe?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this really stack specific? Or is this still [#2](https://github.com/ocramz/petsc-hs/issues/2), e.g. would you prefer/also like a cabal solution?

Comment: @Zeta , I'm still a bit confused about the options. I understood stack requires a fully functional .cabal. In this case I need not only to supply pkgconfig directory and extra includes and libraries, but also to build the new bindings and tell ghci where to find them. I don't understand how to achieve this with .cabal syntax.  I was hoping stack had an option to run a simple macro, or, better still, a makefile, as part of the build.

Comment: @Zeta ok I made some progress: the stack and cabal sandbox builds both work but the linker complains that it cannot find the dynamic libraries produced by inline-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. Read carefully the Stack guide and adhere to the correct .cabal file syntax.

More precisely, when in a similar situation (HaskellC -> C -> Haskell), make sure the .cabal file has:

- Binding libraries within scope by specifying the `include-dirs`, `extra-lib-dirs` and `extra-libraries` field in the `library` stanza.
- the `c-sources` field, pointing to a file with the *same* name as the Haskell file that contains the `inline-c` stuff (i.e. all the `[C.exp| |]` quasiquoters for wrapping C functions) but with the `.c` extension. 
  This will trigger a warning because the C file doesn't exist yet at the beginning  of the build, but it will ALSO call gcc, which will take care of the C output produced by `inline-c`.